# Ionic angular app convert milliseconds to Date Time from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic Mobile App where i receive data from localstorage.

I want to display the milliseconds in to date format. I am following the below code but not able to get the result. Please suggest where i am doing the mistake

Localstorage has data as below:

```
{"data":[[0,"1599843000000"],[1,"1599929580000"],[2,"1600448100000"],[3,"1599843360000"],[4,"1599843420000"],[5,"1599843420000"]]}

1599843000000 is milliseconds
```

Now i want to display all the records in date time format like below.

```
Fri 11 September 2020 22:20:00
```

my home.html looks like below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items[0]" >
      <ion-item no-lines *ngIf='this.items!= 0'>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <h3 ion-text>
              {{item [0]}}
            </h3>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <h3 ion-text>
              {{item [1]}}
            </h3>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
```

my home.ts for saving the data in localstorage looks like below:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("dataset"))
      {
        var dataset = {data: []};
        localStorage.setItem("dataset", JSON.stringify(dataset));
      }
```

my home.ts for retrieve the data from localstorage looks like below:

```
var datasetData = localStorage.getItem("dataset");

let datasetArray = JSON.parse(datasetData );

this.datasetlength= dataset.data.length;

    var dataArray = new Array();

    for (var i=0;i<this.datasetlength;++i){
        dataArray [i] = datasetArray .data[i];
      }

    var dataArraysortedarray = dataArray ;

    this.items.push(dataArraysortedarray );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Angular [Date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) pipe.

In your case,

```html
{{ Number(item [1]) | date:'medium' }}
```

There are a lot of formats you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values like this:

```
const date = new Date(dateInMilliSeconds);
```

Then you can format it using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods.

Alternatively, you can use a library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/):

```
import { fromUnixTime, format } from 'date-fns';

const date = fromUnixTime(dateInMilliseconds);
const dateFormatted = format(date, 'E d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```